# Test if adjacent cells is blank from a formula

Tags: excel

```
A1 = if(A2<0, "A2", "")
```

The cell `A1` will either contain data from cell `A2`or be blank.
I wanted to know how to test in `B1` if `A1` is blank or not. I tried `istext(A1)` or `not(isblank(A1))` but both result in `True` because it is reading the formula and not what the condition of `A1` produces.  How would I go about solving this? Thanks!

Comment: I think the formula you've mentioned in the question should be modified to: =IF(A2<0, A2, "") i.e. there should be no quotes around A2 in the second argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test if a cell is not blank use `<>` and  `""`.

```
IF( A1 <> "", "Not Blank", "Is Blank" )
```

Comment: YES this works! specifically for my example I did something like this, in B1, if (A1 <>"", A1, "")